# unfortunately app closed error in android app when i debug the code

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have developed an app in android to find power shut down.When i run the app ,unfortunately closed once I debug the app.Here I got the error in doInbackground

My java code is here

```
private static final String URL = "http://livechennai.com/powershutdown_news_chennai.asp";
//private static final String URL = "http://livechennai.com/powercut_schedule.asp";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
EditText filterItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<String> hrefs=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            // Connect to website
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            // Get the html document title
            websiteTitle = document.title();
            Elements table=document.select("#table13>tbody>tr>td>a[title]");
            for(Element link:table){
                hrefs.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
                //int arraySize=hrefs.size();
                //websiteDescription=link.attr("abs:href");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //get the array list values
        for(String s:hrefs)
        {
            websiteDescription=hrefs.get(0);
            websiteDescription1=hrefs.get(1);
            websiteDescription2=hrefs.get(2);
            websiteDescription3=hrefs.get(3);
        }
```

Below is the error log

```
06-09 23:17:10.284  17923-17937/com.example.poweralert.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
            at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:60)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:30)
            at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
            at com.example.poweralert.app.PrimaryActivity$FetchWebsiteData.doInBackground(PrimaryActivity.java:144)
            at com.example.poweralert.app.PrimaryActivity$FetchWebsiteData.doInBackground(PrimaryActivity.java:100)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
06-09 23:17:10.
```

How to solve this error/issue? It shows null in website description .

Comment: Like the error says, just use the valid URL

Comment: edited ,i can check the URL also.it will be fine ..try and give a solution

Comment: how can i solve this issue

Comment: Is your application running behind a proxy or firewall connection ? Maybe the URL is blocked ?

Comment: i run the app through mobile internet ...

Comment: I tried running your code and I get a ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) in my logs

Comment: few months back ..it was working good..how to solve this issue

Comment: Dude, things keep changing time to time.This is not the standalone code.Things would have changed at the server end.Try hitting another url and try your luck.

Comment: @GrlsHu have a look pls

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an error in URL connection. Are you not passing valid URL?
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL

Comment: Try with URLConnection class for connecting to URL instead of jsoup.

Comment: I used Jsoup for parsing URL content ...few days back it is working fine